# Unable to get desired output in a Tkinter window for a line graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, tkinter, graph

I'm new to coding and i'm trying to create a Tkinter window using Matplotlib classes that allows me to manipulate a line graph depicting the share prices for 4 companies over two years in a separate window, this is the code I've written:

```
from tkinter import *

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg,NavigationToolbar2Tk)

from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler

from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import pandas as pd
root = Tk ()

data = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\shares.csv')
df = data.iloc[:,:5]
print(df)
print()

fig = Figure( figsize = (20,5) , dpi = 100 )

ax1 = fig.add_subplot()

df.plot('Date',figsize = (20,5),  ax = ax1)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg ( fig , root )

canvas.draw()

canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side = TOP, fill = BOTH, expand = 1)

df.plot(kind = 'bar' , ax = ax1)

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, root)

toolbar.update()

canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side = TOP, fill = BOTH, expand = 1)

def on_key(event):
    print('You Pressed {}'.format(event.key))
    key_press_handler(event, canvas, toolbar)
    
canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event' , on_key)  
  
def Quit():
    root.quit()
    root.destroy()
    return

button = Button(root, text = 'QUIT' , command = Quit )

button.pack ()
root.mainloop()
```

This is the output I have obtained:

[image]

Whereas this is the desired graph:

[image]

I would appreciate any input as to how I can fix this, and make my code better.

Thanks :)

Comment: just saying `root.destroy()` is enought, nd udh to return anything _i dont think, dis is a fix to the issue, but its an improvement_

Comment: Try removing `kind = 'bar'` from `df.plot(kind = 'bar' , ax = ax1)`.

Comment: @CoolCloud Thank you did not realize, much appreciated, have a great day!

Comment: @acw1668 yes this is a mistake on my part thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it may work

```
df.plot(kind = 'line' , ax = ax1)
```

You are ploting `bar` and your expected output is a `line` graph

Comment: Thank you, it works now, mistake on my part, have a great day!